# How can I modify the last iteration of a Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, tostring

Currently, I have the following map

```
Array.map(i => `${i},`)
```

It returns

```
element1,element2,element3,
```

But I would need it to return

```
element1,element2,element3
```

Avoiding the last comma.

How can I do that in a functional way?

Comment: Why not just [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: Is your desired output a string or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const test = [ 'element1', 'element2', 'element3' ];

const asString = test.join();
console.log(asString);
```

[**Note**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484496/how-can-i-modify-the-last-iteration-of-a-array-map/67484536?noredirect=1#comment119280292_67484536): `join()`'s default separator is a comma (`,`)
You can specify a other sepearor as first agument, eg: `join('-')`

Comment: You know, [The default separator is a comma (,)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp). So you can simplify do this `console.log(test .join());`

Answer (score 2):

That better approach to solving this particular problem is probably to use `join` and not `map`.

However, to solve this with map, look at the other arguments passed to the callback:

```
map((element, index, array) => { ... } )
```

You can determine if you are on the last element using `index === array.length - 1`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do that in a functional way?

```js
console.log(
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].reduce((x, y) => `${x},${y}`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`.toString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) or [`.join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) like this.

```js
const arr = [ 'element1', 'element2', 'element3' ];
console.log(arr.toString());
console.log(arr.join()); // The same as console.log(arr.join(','));
```

> The `toString()` method returns a string with all the array values,
> *separated by commas*.

> The `join()` method returns the array as a string.
> The elements will be separated by a specified separator. *The default
> separator is a comma (,).*